# All categories options or All categories not Populating

Tags: php, functions, categories

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <?php
        if ( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
            echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option>Select category...</option>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
            endforeach;
            echo '</select>';
        endif;
    ?>
</form>
```

This populates something like this →

[image]

Is there a method through which I can also get an options selected by defaulty that populates all categories.

Comment: Hmm... What do you mean by "get an options selected by defaulty that populates all categories"? What exactly is your question?

Comment: That means when no category is selected initially when the page loads for the first time the posts of all the categories should populate.

Comment: And how do you populate the posts? The code you’ve shown is responsible only for showing this select field..